# Eliminate the difference in the way frame ticks look in a list plot vs a curve plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

How do I control the Frame Tick Style on all axes using `Plot`?

I am seeking to control the Frame Tick style in two similar graphs, but I am getting different results from `ListPlot` vs from `Plot`.

This code gives a plot with the specified format on all four axes:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 10}, PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledUpTriangle], 20}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 4000}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 FrameStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}, 
                     {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16, FontWeight -> Bold, Black},
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}
]
```

This nearly identical code gives a plot with the desired ticks on the left and bottom axes, but default ticks on the other two:

```
Plot[{M}, {M, 15, 35}, PlotRange -> {0, 200},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 FrameStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}},
                     {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16, FontWeight -> Bold, Black},
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}
]
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the problem. This is what I see when I execute your code: [capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xH15x.png), where the top is `ListPlot` and the bottom is from `Plot`. The styles look very similar to me. Perhaps you should include your own output and point out the differences in detail. I am on MMA v. 11.2, Win7-64.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the only reason you see a difference is because your plot ranges disagree. If you make them the same there will be no difference.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Subdivide[2, 28, 10], Subdivide[2, 38, 10]}],
  PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledUpTriangle], 20}},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 40}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> 
    {{{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}, 
     {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}},
  LabelStyle -> 
    {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16, FontWeight -> Bold, Black}, 
 BaseStyle -> 
   {FontWeight -> "Bold", Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

[image: list_plot]

```
Plot[{4 M/3}, {M, 0, 30},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {.0, 40}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> 
    {{{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}, 
     {{Thickness[0.003], Black}, {Thickness[0.003], Black}}},
  LabelStyle -> 
    {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16, FontWeight -> Bold, Black}, 
 BaseStyle -> 
   {FontWeight -> "Bold", Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

[image: line_plot]

Comment: Here is what I get